# Android Support Repository and Continuous Integration

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm currently moving my project to Gradle, this project with mutliple branches is currently being built by Jenkins.

After building the application fine in Android Studio, I have pushed my commits and have run into a little snag: Jenkins doesn't seem to understand where to find the support libraries.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android_Alpha_Gradle'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':HereAndNowAPI'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':HereAndNowAPI:_debugCompile'.


 Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0.
    Searched in the following locations:

        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.0/appcompat-v7-19.0.0.pom
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.0/appcompat-v7-19.0.0.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.0/appcompat-v7-19.0.0.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/19.0.0/appcompat-v7-19.0.0.jar

    Required by:
        Android_Alpha_Gradle:HereAndNowAPI:unspecified

 Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0.
    Searched in the following locations:

        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.0/support-v4-22.2.0.jar

    Required by:
        Android_Alpha_Gradle:HereAndNowAPI:unspecified
```

Obviously this machine is headless and I'm not exactly sure how I can install the Android Support Repository via the command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this awesome SDK Manager plugin

https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Google decided not to publish to JCenter or MavenCentral.  You have to run android sdk update with extra-android-m2repository.  Jake Wharotn's SDK Manager plugin handles this download for you.